# Electric pairs, working in Emacs 24.3, but not in 24.4

Tags: emacs24.4, electric-pair-mode

In 24.3, I have this in my .emacs, and it works:

`(electric-pair-mode 1)`

`(setq electric-pair-pairs '(    (?\" . ?\") (?\{ . ?\}) (?\( . ?\)    ) )`

Normally I use this in org-mode. All of them worked in 24.3, but only {}, and [] works in 24.4.

The new version is loading the same .emacs.

Comment: FWIW, if I try `emacs24 -Q -f electric-pair-mode ~/tmp/foo.org` I can then use `(`, `"`, and `{` to insert the corresponding pairs.  This is 24.5, tho.